# Lets Encrypt Certificate not accepted by Internet Explorer

Tags: ssl, certificate, internet-explorer, lets-encrypt

I am a server running `nginx` serving a very simple `Kibana` dashboard.
A client connects to `https://subdomain.domain.eu` served by `nginx`.
This shows a dashboard hosted by kibana on `https://subdomain.domain.eu:5601`

Both `nginx` and `kibana` use the same certificate to serve requests.

All our webbrowsers accept the certificate and show the website correctly.
Only our client has trouble and does not accept this certificate. He is running windows 7 with Internet Explorer. It shows the following error:

```
The security certificate that is used by this website, is issued to another address.
The security certificate that is used by this website, is issued by a non trusted certificate authority.
```

I translated from Dutch, so it might not correspond to the English error text.

I went to the client and he has `DST Root CA X3` as trusted in his certificate store. We are serving the full certificate chain from the server and a test with `ssl labs` gives us an A+.

Comment: has he ever installed windows updates....

Comment: It is a managed desktop. I assumed it is, but I will check. But seeing as `DST root CA x3` is in the certificate store I think this is not a problem.